# Firebase database is throwing "Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to push an object to the firebase database, but the push() method isn't working and it  seems likely it has something to do with the warning I'm getting:

> @firebase/database:, FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly (https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com)

However it matches databaseURL in the config I have in the `App.js`

```
const config = {
apiKey: "<...>",
authDomain: "<...>.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "<...>",
storageBucket: "<...>.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "<...>",
appId: "<...>",
databaseURL: "https://<...>.firebaseio.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

The method I use to get access to the database:

```
 const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
 console.log(currentUser.uid); // works fine
 firebase
     .database()
     .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/cards`)
     .push({some object})
```

I'm using Database location: Belgium (europe-west1) if that matters.
And firebase authentication works fine.

Comment: *firebaser here* Answer on how to fix this is below. But can you tell me where you got that `config` snippet from? I get the correct URL in my tests and if this is a bug I'd love to get it fixed.

Comment: I got the config from firebase except for the `databaseURL` which I added afterwards.

Comment: Hmmm... then where did you get that specific URL value from? Thanks for answering btw, as you're not the only one to have problems here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `databaseURL` in your configuration snippet does not seem to match the actual URL of your database.

I recommend getting the correct URL from [the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database) and putting that in the config.

Comment: It should actually end in `firebasedatabase.app` as far as I can tell. My experience: don't type the URL, but copy/paste it from the console link I provided.

Comment: I typed a bit too fast. The URL ended in fact with  `.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app`

Comment: another option is that the realtime databse wasn't created yet, go to the firebase console and make sure you created a realtime database with that name

Answer (score 1):

In my case, realtime databse wasn't created yet. I faced this issue for below code on react app.

```
set(ref(db,'users/' + userid), {
  username:name,
  email:email,
  profile_picture: uploadLink
})
```

Above syntax for writing to realtime database not firestore

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up when we create a database in Cloud database. Actually, we need to
create a real time database which provides databaseURL.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to create a realtime db on Firebase, tks